# How to know solidity version of remix for already deployed contract

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, remix, etherscan

I recently deployed a smart contact using remix and MyEtherWallet. The contract is deployed successfully.

But when I am trying to verify the contract code on etherscan. I need compiler version for that. But I don't remember what compiler version did I use. Is there any chance of getting that?

I have contract code, abi, address but not solidity version. How can I verify my contract on etherscan. Hit and try are taking very long time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the date of your deployment in [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io), then check for the version of the compiler on that date.

For the future, remember to write a first line of code in your solidity contract that specifies this, for example:

> pragma solidity 0.4.19

Answer (score 0):

You can find it at the top-right corner

[image]